# Save form parameters on hash change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, location

I'm developing a web application that uses AJAX technology to load the pages and each page contains a form that is submited via POST.

In order to use browser back and forward buttons I'm detecting hash changes and loading the specific page through `location.hash`.

How can I save the form parameters of each page that was visited? I'm not allowed to use to use GET instead of POST since this is a requirement of the client.

Comment: Can't you send the form data via AJAX using POST, and then send it back in the response?

Comment: @Chevi I'm not fully understanding your solution, could you please elaborate a bit more? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html5 localstorage is one of the solutions..

Links:

[Demo and usage](http://simsalabim.github.com/sisyphus/)

[How to Use..](http://php-html.net/tutorials/html5-local-storage-guide/)